# How to inherit website.homepage and add html content inside div id="wrap" in odoo 12?

Tags: html, odoo, qweb, odoo-12

I am trying to insert some HTML blocks in Odoo12 home page. So I tried inheriting the *website.homepage*. But this is not working. The HTML block that I inserted is not showing in the home page even after upgrading the module. Any help?

```
<template id="my_website_template" name="New Home page" inherit_id="website.homepage">
    <xpath expr="//div[@id='wrap']" position="replace">
        <!--HTML CODE-->
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<record id="homepage_block" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="priority">99</field>
    <field name="name">homepage_block</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="website.layout"/>
    <field name="website_id" search="[('name', 'like', 'My Website')]" model="website"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//div[@id='wrapwrap']" position="replace">
    </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

this replaces the whole website layout. you can play with position="replace" like: position="before" or position="after" etc...

Answer (score 0):

Website homepage is rendered from `homepage_id` field of record in `website` model, which is a related field with model `website.page`.

```
<record id="homepage_page" model="website.page">
  <field name="website_published">True</field>
  <field name="url">/</field>
  <field name="view_id" ref="homepage" />
</record>
<record id="default_website" model="website">
  <field name="homepage_id" ref="homepage_page" />
</record>
```

Instead of inheriting the default `homepage` template, you can inherit `default_website` records `homepage_id` field and set to your own custom page. For example, following example is shown with built in `contactus_page`.

```
<record id="default_website_homepage" model="website">
    <field name="inerit_id" ref="website.default_website"/>       
    <field name="homepage_id" ref="website.contactus_page" />
</record>
```

So by inheriting this record, homepage of the default website is set to contact us page. What you can do is write your own template for example `my_homepage`, use that template in a `website_page` record `my_homepage_page` and set that as default website `homepage_id`

```
<record id="my_homepage" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Home</field>
    <field name="type">qweb</field>
    <field name="key">website.homepage</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <t name="Home" priority="29" t-name="your_module.my_homepage">
            <t t-call="website.layout">
                ....
                ....
            </t>
        </t>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="my_homepage_page" model="website.page">
  <field name="website_published">True</field>
  <field name="url">/</field>
  <field name="view_id" ref="my_homepage" />
</record>

<record id="default_website_homepage" model="website">
    <field name="inerit_id" ref="website.default_website"/>       
    <field name="homepage_id" ref="my_homepage_page" />
</record>
```

Comment: Thank you @arryph. But this is not working. Tried it.

Comment: I even tested the code before posting the answer, it should work. are you sure you installed and updated properly?

Comment: my mistake, removed an extra `inherit_id` attribute from the template.

Comment: I am still getting empty page.. even after updating the module many times

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190041/discussion-between-arryph-and-sfx).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share the version that i use today for Odoo 12.0
Thanks to @arryph for the snippet!

I override the Contact us page from website like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <!-- === Contact us Page === -->
    <template id="custom_contactus_page_template">
       <t t-call="website.layout">
            <div id="wrap" class="oe_structure oe_empty">
                <!-- Your page content here! -->
            </div>
        </t>
    </template>

    <record id="custom_contactus_page" model="website.page">
        <field name="name">Contact us</field>
        <field name="website_published">True</field>
        <field name="url">/contactus</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="custom_contactus_page_template"/>
    </record>

    <!-- Contact us Menu Page-->
    <record id="custom_contactus_nav" model="website.menu">
        <field name="name">Contact us</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="website.menu_contactus"/>
        <field name="page_id" ref="custom_contactus_page"/>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

As documentation suggest, i prefer to use `<template>` instead of `<record><t-name>` because `<template>` is more easy to extend with xpath.

[Website Theme Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/themes.html#create-a-specific-page-layout)

> It is worth mentioning there is an alternative to create pages using
>   the  directive we saw before. This would allow your page
>   content to be further customized using .

**EDIT**

Anyway, i think that will work too override the website.menu item as shown:

```
<!-- Contact us Menu Page-->
<record id="website.menu_contactus" model="website.menu">
    <field name="name">Contact us</field>
    <field name="page_id" ref="custom_contactus_page"/>
</record>
```

This will change the page_id of the object website.menu_contactus 
**I don't test that code, but i think that will work.**

OR

You can simply create a new one page, with same url, and from website, configuration-> pages just archive the page /contactus generated by website and magically your page with same url will be shown.
Like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <!-- === Contact us Page === -->
    <template id="custom_contactus_page_template">
       <t t-call="website.layout">
            <div id="wrap" class="oe_structure oe_empty">
                <!-- Your page content here! -->
            </div>
        </t>
    </template>

    <record id="custom_contactus_page" model="website.page">
        <field name="name">Contact us</field>
        <field name="website_published">True</field>
        <field name="url">/contactus</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="custom_contactus_page_template"/>
    </record>

    <!-- Contact us Menu Page-->
    <record id="your_custom_nav_item" model="website.menu">
        <field name="name">Contact me</field>
        <field name="page_id" ref="custom_contactus_page"/>
        <field name="parent_id" ref="website.main_menu"/>
        <field name="sequence" type="int">60</field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

And after that archive the page /contactus from website configurations.

Answer (score 0):

From [Abishek Kumar](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/how-do-i-change-the-default-template-of-odoo-website-119561) on the odoo forum, I have tried it and it works well :

```
  <template id="theme_custom.new_homepage" inherit_id="website.homepage">
        <xpath expr="//div[@id='wrap']" position="replace">
          <div id="wrap" class="oe_structure">
              hello
          </div>
        </xpath>
    </template>
```